# Why do isnan, isinf, and isfinite return an int and not a bool?

Tags: c++, floating-point, c++11, nan, infinite

[isnan](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/isnan) returns an int... `nonzero value if arg is NaN, ​0​ otherwise`. Why doesn't it return a bool? This isn't some legacy stuff, it's new with C++11.

Comment: Probably because this comes from the days _C_ didn't had a _boolean_ type...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It **is** legacy stuff, these are found in `<cmath>`, which is the C standard library `<math.h>` put into the `std` namespace.  C doesn't have a native `bool` type.<sup>1</sup>

Whilst it's true that these are a C++11 addition, they are essentially pulling in stuff that was added to `<math.h>` in C99.

---

<sub>1. For those about to complain, C99's `bool` is actually a macro.  There is a `_Bool`, but I guess the C99 authors chose not to use it for `isnan` *et al.* in order to retain consistency with other stuff in `<math.h>`.</sub>

Comment: C99's type _Bool is not a macro because _Bool is a C99 keyword.

Comment: Then the comment about bool doesn't make any sense. isnan could return _Bool (or bool which is #defined to _Bool). I think the reason it's not is because C99 isnan is based of even earlier non-standard definitions where there really wasn't a bool type.

Comment: @bames53: The comment about bool is just a disclaimer to prevent people about to contest my claim that C99 doesn't have a `bool` type.  I agree, C99's `isnan` probably *could* have been defined to return a `_Bool`, but that would be a discussion for a question about C...

Comment: @bames53: Ah, I now see what you mean.  Footnote adjusted!

Comment: I always thought isnan comes fromt he BSD 4.3 times... anyways, isn't if in C defined to "compare unequal to 0" ?

Answer (score 0):

To clarify, isnan, isinf were added as macro's in C99 as int expressions. So for C compatibility it makes sense to add them as functions returning int.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/isnan/

> C99 C++11
>
> In C, this is implemented as a macro that returns an int value. The
>   type of x shall be float, double or long double